# Java code length -1 meaning

Tags: java

```
class Zillion {

    private int zilly[];

    public Zillion(int size){
        zilly = new int[size];
    }

    public void increment(){
        int i=zilly.length -1;
        while(i>=0){
            if(zilly[i]!=9){
                zilly[i]+=1;
                i=-1;
            }
            else{
                zilly[i]=0;
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
```

I just got a basic java code like this and do not know what length -1 means at this part  `(int i=zilly.length -1;)`.
Can someone please explain this ?

Comment: The highest valid index of the `zilly[]` array is `zilly.length - 1`.  Hence, the code is iterating over this array backwards, starting at the highest position.

Comment: What on earth is this code doing? it looks like it would just always terminate on the initial iteration because i would become -1... ?

Comment: @Jay If you do a desk test you probably can figure out on your own how it works.

Comment: And on top of that. consider using your favorite search engine the next time. Surprisingly enough, you are *not* the first newbie wondering about the basics of java. Keep that simple truth in mind when looking into the next basic java thing.

Answer (score 2):

The size of array is the number of elements in this array, but The first index of arrays is 0. For example :

```
int zilly[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

In this example :

`zilly.size` return : 4

But `zilly[4]` not exist because the index of the first element is 0

`zilly.[zilly.size - 1]` return the last element (4).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Except for the fact that the OP asks about arrays, and you talk about ArrayLists, as if they were the same. Hint: they are not. And lists dont have a **length** field.

Answer (score 1):

`nameOfTable.lenght` return the number of element 
the first index of `Arrays` start with 0 ==> `(1st - 1 = 0)` ,
so the last index is `n - 1`

Answer (score 0):

It means that we want to get the last index in the array.
And then we loop over the array from end to start.

`zilly.length` it's the array size - but the array's index starts from 0 so the last index is `zilly.length-1`

Comment: As in computer science we start the index at 0 instead of 1 when we're going to the end of a list say of length 10 we need to access the index 9 for a list of length n the last item will be `n-1`

Answer (score 0):

`int i=zilly.length -1;` is the last index of the array, because arrays start at index `0`.

A side note, the formatting of this code be improved to better portray what it's doing, for example the line that confused you could be.

`int i = zilly.length - 1;` simply spacing out the statement correctly makes it a bit easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

`zilly.length -1` defines itself. Total array length (size) -1.

Since the first index of array starts with `0` so the last item is at position `n-1` where `n` is the size of array.

Answer (score 0):

In Java indexing of arrays starts from 0. Therefore the last element of arrays is accessed by `zilly[zilly.length - 1]`. If you try to access it this way:

```
zilly[zilly.length]
```

you will get an out of bounds exception.

The while loop in your code starts from the last index and iterates down the very first element.

Answer (score 0):

`zilly.length` gives the length of the array, i.e. the number of elements in it.

`zilly.length-1` gives the last index of the array because the count of the array begins from 0.

So basically you are iterating in a descending order, i.e. from the last element of the array to the first element of the array.